# Output Sound Device (Alesis I02 audio interface) does not appear in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, audio, device-manager

I have just installed a new Audio Interface on my PC running Windows 7.
It works fine as an input device.. (and appears as a sound input device in Windows as one would expect).

However.. this device does not appear as an output device in Windows (it has both input & output capability).

[This means I can not select this playback recordings from my SonarLE programme for example].

Confession : I may have accidentally switched something off first time early after install when I first ran SonarLE which was related to this.